# How can i make a generic variable without using generics?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class,

```
class ComputeScalar<T> : IComputeVariable where T : struct
{
   // This is why i have to use generics.
   ComputeBuffer<T> buffer;

   T data;
}

class ComputeArray<T> : IComputeVariable where T : struct
{
   // This is why i have to use generics.
   ComputeBuffer<T> buffer;

   T[] data;
}
```

and i use this class in a list in another class,

```
class SomeClass
{
   List<IComputeVariable> variables;
}
```

I created the interface because in C# we can't use generic classes for type parameters. (Right?) What i want to learn is how can i make **"data"** a member of interface? And during runtime how can i determine type of data?
(Data can be any ValueType)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could only make `data` a member of the interface by making it weakly typed as `object`:

```
public interface IComputeVariable
{
    object Data { get; }
}
```

(Note that it has to be a property - you can't specify fields in interfaces.)

You'd then probably want to implement that explicitly in `ComputeScalar<T>`, to avoid the weakly typed version from being used where the strongly typed version was available.

An alternative would be to make the interface generic, *and `SomeClass` too*:

```
class SomeClass<T> where T : struct
{
   List<IComputeVariable<T>> variables;
}
```

We don't really know enough about your situation to know which is the right approach, but those are two of your options.

Comment: The buffer is used for sending data to gpu and has to be generic. So second alternative is not an option because there are different types of variable i need to send to gpu. List has to be generic. But i ll try first one.
thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
interface IComputeVariable<T> where T : struct
{
  T Data { get; }
}

class ComputeScalar<T> : IComputeVariable<T> where T : struct
{
   // This is why i have to use generics.
   ComputeBuffer<T> buffer;

   public T Data {get; set; }
}
```